# Printing ConfigObj

Tags: python, for-loop, configobj

I have very simple problem I want to print everything that's inside session.ini

But it doesn't let me the output is: **>> {}**

Does somebody have a trick how to print everything inside the session.ini

*inside:* **session.ini**

```
[Session 1]
Data = "session_1.db"

[Session 2]
Data = "session_1.db"
```

*The* **code**:

```
session = ConfigObj("sessions.ini")

def Session():
    for item in session:
      print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me with Python 2.7.5 and your .ini file, so I can't reproduce the problem. Have I missed something?

Note: You're opening a file called `sessions.ini` but your question shows it under a heading that says `session.ini` -- without the `'s'`. That might be the cause...

```
from configobj import ConfigObj

session = ConfigObj("sessions.ini", raise_errors=True)

def Session():
    for item in session:
        print(item)

Session()
```

Output:

```
Session 1
Session 2
```

Comment: Thank you that was the problem.
This only printed the headlines Session 1, Session 2
What if I want to print the lines under like Data = "session_1.db"

Comment: `ConfigObj` is a subclass of `Section`, which is a subclass of `dict`, so you could use `for n, s in session.iteritems():` where each `n` is a `Section`'s name and each `s` is a `Section` object -- which, like a nested `dict`, would need a nested `for` to iterate over its contents (name, value pairs).

Comment: Understood. What if I wanted to print what `Data` is assigned to in this case: `Session_1.db` `Session_2.db` 
And not everything `{'Data': 'session_1.db'}`
Sorry for these questions after each other should posted this in one comment.

Comment: `print session['Session 1']['Data']` --> `session_1.db`. A `ConfigObj` behaves a lot like a dictionary of dictionaries. The [online documention](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html) is pretty good, check it out.